# How do I make the text and right chevron align right on the footer?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web-frontend

I got the left side to line up but can't get the right side to work. I tried `pull-right`, `float:right`, `text-align:right`, but none of them work. Here is my code. Appreciate any help[image: ![Footer image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Nit.png)

```
 <footer class="footer clearfix">
       <div class="footer-grid">
          <div class="footer-L col-md-6">
          <a class="footer-text" href="hysys.html">
            <span>Previous</span>
             <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
              <h2>HYSYS<h2>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-R col-md-6 pull-right">
            <a class="footer-text" href="hysys.html">
            <span>Next</span>
             <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
              <h2>Aspen One</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Trying to post the CSS, but it kept on telling me it's too long....

Comment: Then add only the CSS that is relevant to these HTML elements?

Comment: Or put it inside of a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/98jdfy4t/

Comment: It would be best to edit the HTML in this scenario, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/nf49e1Lp/

Comment: Although if you cannot control the markup, I was able to get your arrow to appear to the right by adding this css: `i.fa-arrow-right { left: 65px; }`